# Storing app-specific data in Android storage (internal or external)

Tags: android, storage

I want to store some media files(mp3) in either external storage (if available) or internal storage.

I've done some reading on the Android developer page and it says that by default only folders stored in internal storage are app-specific and cannot be accessed by other apps or the user.

However, since it may storage space might be limited on some devices, one may want to consider external storage. The issue with this is that other apps can access you folder and read its contents.

Is there a proper way of the files such that they are completely accessible only from my app regardless of whether they are in internal or external storage, preferably a method that doesn't involve encrypting the folder?

Comment: I do not think that this is possible without encryption.

Comment: @Christopher ok, do you know of any simple encryption options?